# Seat vs sit as a verb

Tags: verbs

Is it correct grammar to say "I was supposed to seat there" if we use the word "seat" as a verb? I know that it is correct to say "I was supposed to sit there", which is more common. For example, we can also use "seat" as a verb in the sentence "Please seat him down", right?

Comment: Did you look up "seat" in the dictionary? If that did not solve your problem edit your question to add what you found and why it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I did, actually. "Seat" can be used as a verb AND as a noun.

Comment: "I was supposed to **be** seat**ed** there."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's definitely a grammatical error, but it's not idiomatic.  Generally the verb seat is transitive, with the thing being installed in the seat (if specified) being the object of the verb.  However, the verb can be used in a intransitive sense, with the installed thing being the subject -- it's an uncommon use but not technically wrong.

Comment: Right, maybe. (Why do I say maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

"I was supposed to seat there" does not make sense because "seat" is different from the action of "sit" done by the subject "I".  As your example illustrated, the action "seat" is applied to an object ("Please seat him down").

Comment: "I was supposed to seat there" makes sense when said by one usher to another.